# Constants Differ in SHA1 implementation

Tags: hash, sha-1

I am trying to understand why the constants differ in this SHA1 implementation:

1. https://code.google.com/p/crypto-js/source/browse/tags/3.1.2/src/sha1.js

   ```
   this._hash = new WordArray.init([
       0x67452301, 0xefcdab89,
       0x98badcfe, 0x10325476,
       0xc3d2e1f0
   ]);
   ```
2. https://code.google.com/p/google-authenticator/source/browse/libpam/totp.html

   ```
   V = 0x67452301,
   W = 0x88888888,
   Y = 271733878,
   X = Y ^ W,
   Z = 0xC3D2E1F0;
   ```

You'll notice the constants in [1] and [2] are different. Is this the result of an optimization, or is there another reason why those constants are different?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

They are actually the same, because you missed `W^=V` in the second link. When you work out the XORs, you arrive at the same constants.

Comment: Yes, and it appears to be an optimization to save code space, as there is 1 less constant

Comment: And what a strange optimization it is: 2 characters less for 2 XORs.

Comment: Same thing with the Y value, it only saves 1 byte of code space